# Logs and Server Console

Tags: java, logging

I am studyin the logs overview from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#1.15
and i have the following problem. I have created a simple WEB Application and i use the following code:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet.severe");
    Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet.Fine");
    Handler fh=new FileHandler("/C:/Html/mylogs.txt");
    Handler fh2=new FileHandler("/C:/Html/mylogs2.txt");
    //Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet").addHandler(fh);
    //Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet.Fine").addHandler(fh2);
   // Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
   // Logger.getLogger("com.NewServlet.Fine").setLevel(Level.FINE);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String number=request.getParameter("value");
    Integer num=Integer.valueOf(number);
    int a= num.parseInt(number);
    int result=0;
    try {
        /*
         * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
         */
        result=20/a;
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        //logger2.fine("doing stuff");
        logger2.addHandler(fh2);
        logger2.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        logger2.fine("doing ALL OK");
        //logger2.log(Level.FINE,"doing OK");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + result + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }
    catch ( Exception e1){
        logger.addHandler(fh); 
        logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "troubles", e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }

    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the log message is displayed twice ( one in the Server Console and one in the Logs file , what can i do so that i can see the message only the log file and not in the Console?) and the other problem is that for the logger with Lever SEVERE i see the error messages only in the Server Console. The .txt mylogs.txt that is been created is empty. Why this happen?

Comment: Because, you are using e1.printStackTrace(); This will write to the console which is default to server log.

Answer (score 0):

`e1.printStackTrace();` will print the stack trace in the console. Remove that and print the stack trace in the log file as (which you are already doing)

`logger.log(LEVEL, MSG, EXCEPION_OBJECT)`

When you set the logger level as `SEVERE` [has the highest value], all levels below that will be discarded and they will not be printed to the file.

Rename your logfiles' extension from `.txt` to `.log`

```
Handler fh=new FileHandler("/C:/Html/mylogs.log");
Handler fh2=new FileHandler("/C:/Html/mylogs2.log");
```

Comment: i did it, when i have an exception now everythng works fine but when the code does not have any exception the logger2 is empty and the Server console shows the relevant message that i have defined in FINE level, is that reasonable?

Comment: So, things are fine if you are able to see `logger2.log()` messages in `mylogs2.log` file and exception messages in `mylogs.log` file.